# Prevent internal POST methods to be called by third parties

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, security

I'm worried about the security of my web app, I'm using Django and sometimes I use AJAX to call a Django url that will execute code and then return an HttpResponse with a message according the result, the user never notice this as it's happening in background.

However, if the url I'm calling with AJAX is, for example, "runcode/", and the user somehow track this and try to send a request to my domain with that url (something like "www.example.com/runcode/"), it will not run the code as Django expects the csrf token to be send too, so here goes the question.

It is possible that the user can obtain the csrf token and send the POST?, I feel the answer for that will be "yes", so anyone can help me with a hint on how to deny these calls if they are made without the intended objective?

Comment: Unless it serves only static content, any request to your server will make it run code. So what would be different in your situation?

Comment: Usually, the code executed is just the render of an html template, but this other URLs sometimes manage sensitive data or sometimes execute a query on a backend server, so I think it can be dangerous is someone discover these URLs, I'm reading about this and seems like csrf tokens cover this, but I'm not 100% that why I'm asking @ThierryLathuille

Comment: Calling URLs and having code run is the basis of all web applications. If a view manages sensitive data then you need some kind of authentication on the URL to only allow certain users to access it

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's happening in the background or what. Your web server will ***do things*** in certain situations, e.g. when a specific URL is being requested. Now, are those ***things*** *dangerous* in any way? If so, then don't do them! If not, then what are you worried about exactly? Can the user pass any code to the server and the server will blindly execute whatever code the user provided? Then yeah, that's bad. If not, again, what are you worried about?

Comment: @deceze I cannot just don't do them, as I need to do them, I already clarified my worries reading a lot the Django documentation, my principal point to be worry about is that I implement a POST method then anyone could just send a POST to that URL with different data, but that's actually not possible, as Django request the csrf token to be on the request body of the POST, so understanding how the csrf token works really solved my question. And I will need to camouflage my POST request so if a GET is received it should redirect to a 404

Comment: Yeah, in general, *anyone can send any request to your server at any time.* That's a fact of operating a public web server on the public interweb. You can't prevent that. The CSRF token only prevents certain automated attacks, it doesn't prevent that general fact. You simply must expect your method to be invoked by anyone at any time, and *validate* the request accordingly, perhaps requiring authentication too.

Comment: @deceze As you stated, I feel the correct way is to validate the request accordingly, and in the cases where critical information is being managed I should require authentication, thanks a lot, I consider this proceeding as the correct answer of my question, so feel free to post it and I will accept it

Comment: @deceze I just edited my question

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other comments, the purpose of web apps is to execute code based on user interactions. Sometimes the code simply results in the display of another html templates while in other cases it results in other code executions.

If your concern is around unauthorized users gaining access to sensitive data, django has built in tools to help with authentication/authorization.

Would recommend you read up on it:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/

Comment: This is more accurate to me, as it includes references to the documentation about the authentication everybody is asking me to implement, thanks, but after a lot of documentation reading, I finally understood that the solution to my worries is the csrf token

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Not only django but this behavior is common in all others,

You can only apply 2 solution,

1. Apply CORS and just allow your domain, to block other domain to access data from your API response, but this will not effective if a user direct call your API end-point.
2. As lain said in comment, If data is sensitive or user's personal, add authentication in API.

Thanks